# How to skip !@Fharb, $Recycle.Bin Config.Msi, Recovery and so on (such as systemFiles ) using std::directoryIterator (c++)?

Tags: c++, directory, filesystems

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
for (const auto &pfile : std::directory_iterator(path))
{
 // Get name and then, I wanna skip above subject files... 
 // (!@FHarb,$Recycle.Bin, Config.Msi, Recovery, Documents and Settings and so on such as system files)
    auto name = pfile.path().filename().u8string();
}
```

I recently "std::filesystem::directory_iterator" in vs2017

I wanna skip above files but directory options I found is not effective (none, follow directory symlink)

Comment: What's stopping you from maintaining your custom list of directory entries to ignore, and, well, ignoring them?

Comment: What's wrong with let's say using a `std::regex` checking `name` to filter inside the loop?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik there are many files related systemfiles so it is difficult to make custom prevent files.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  std::regex is not perfect because there are common files name equal to systemfiles

Comment: Even if there are 20 files, it shouldn't be rocket science to maintain a list of files to skip. This is what arrays or sets are for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik what is rocket science :)? I don't know that (rocket science)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik localisation of system folder names may make list of names a problem.

Comment: @Lucius__ I don't see why `std::regex` shouldn't be suitable to determine these _""special"_ path names. I've written an answer, which does what you want in a more generic way, feel free to use something suitable for you in the predicate function which determines what to filter out.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanna skip above files but directory options I found is not effective (none, follow directory symlink)

Sure, `std::filesystem::directory_options` serve a different purpose. To cite the documentation found in [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_options):

> > This type represents available options that control the behavior of the  directory_iterator and recursive_directory_iterator.
> >
> > `directory_options` satisfies the requirements of *BitmaskType* (which means the bitwise operators `operator&`, `operator|`, `operator^`, `operator~`, `operator&=`, `operator|=`, and `operator^=` are defined for this type). none represents the empty bitmask; every other enumerator represents a distinct bitmask element.
> >
> > **Member constants**
> >
> > ```
> > +--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
> > | Member constant          | Meaning                                      |  
> > +--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
> > | none   (Default)         | Skip directory symlinks, permission denied   |  
> > |                          | is error.                                    |
> > +--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
> > | follow_directory_symlink | Follow rather than skip directory symlinks.  |
> > +--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
> > | skip_permission_denied   | Skip directories that would otherwise result |  
> > |                          | in permission denied errors.                 |
> > +-----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
> > ```

There'
s no consideration of what you call *system files* in the c++ standards filesystem notion.
You can use the standard c++ algorithm functions though, to easily filter entries from `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` though. Just do something like the following:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

template <typename pred>
fs::directory_iterator get_filtered_entries
    (const fs::directory_iterator& dir_iter, pred pred_op) {
    return std::find_if(fs::begin(dir_iter),fs::end(dir_iter),pred_op);
}

int main() {
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/a/b");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file1.txt");
    std::ofstream("sandbox/file2.txt");
    
    auto dir_iter = fs::directory_iterator("sandbox");
    auto filtered_entries = get_filtered_entries(dir_iter,
         // Place whatever predicate is appropriate to filter out specific entries
         // from the directory
         [](const fs::directory_entry& entry) { 
             return entry.path().string() == "sandbox/file1.txt"; });
    std::for_each(fs::begin(filtered_entries),fs::end(filtered_entries),
         [](const fs::directory_entry& entry) { std::cout << entry.path() << '\n'; });

    fs::remove_all("sandbox");
}
```

Output:

```
"sandbox/file1.txt"
"sandbox/a"
```

See the [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ded02b225b3de42).